# Почему не работает юникодное свойство \p{L} в JS?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, jsp

Почему регулярное выражение вида:

```
const validAccountFirstName = new RegExp("^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}{3,50}$");
или
const validAccountFirstName = /^\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}{3,50}$/;
```

Сама проверка:

```js
const accountFirstName = document.getElementById("account_first_name");
const descriptionAccountFirstName = document.getElementById("description_account_first_name");

accountFirstName.oninput = function() {
        if(validAccountFirstName.test(accountFirstName.value)) {
            descriptionAccountFirstName.style.color = "green";
        } else {
            descriptionAccountFirstName.style.color = "red";
        }
    };
```

не работает на `JSP` странице вообще (на ввод любых строк)? Хотя на [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3RerBA/1) оно работает?

Однако, работает регулярное выражение вида:

```
const validAccountFirstName = /^[A-Z][a-z]{3,50}$/;
```

Вот как выглядит подключение файла `validation.js` на JSP странице:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>

<fmt:setLocale value="${sessionScope.locale_page}"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="locale"/>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/validation.js"></script>
</head>
```

Что я пробовал (это не работает):

- [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
  Что я не так делаю?

Firefox 90.0 (64-bit)

Comment: В первом варианте (new RegExp) не хватает бекслешей, а во втором наоборот лишние

Comment: @AlexeyTen, про первый вариант - это какой именно?

Comment: Самый первый код в вопросе

Comment: @AlexeyTen, т.е. должно быть так - `const validAccountFirstName = new RegExp("^\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}{3,50}$");` ?

Comment: Да.  Но ещё надо флаг `u` добавить https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes

Comment: @AlexeyTen, `const validAccountFirstName = new RegExp("^\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}{3,50}$/u");` - так верно?

Comment: Нет. Неверно. Посмотрите в документации как правильно указывать флаги

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Спасибо за помощь **[@AlexeyTen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190728/alexey-ten)**.

Например:

```js
const regexpAccountFirstName = /^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}{2,50}$/u;
const regexpCompanyAddress = new RegExp("[\\p{Alpha}\\p{P}\\p{Zs}]{3,200}$", "u");
```